# on_reaction_add not being called in discord.py

Tags: python, android-intent, discord.py, call, onready

I have this weird issue, ive read all the documentation regarding reactions, but with my code it just doesnt get called!

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    print('reaction added')
```

The code above doesnt get called!?!? Furthermore when I use `on_raw_reaction_add` it makes no difference!? Ive tried everything I can think of, I've run it in my cogs:

```
@Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
  print("detected")
```

```
@Cog.listener()
async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction, user):
  print("detected")
```

It never works!?!?!? I know the bot doesnt detect a reaction before start unless you use raw! but ive tried both! Please help, I'm also aware you need intents, and they are all setup properly:

```
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, members=True)
key2=os.getenv('key2')
key=os.getenv('key')
wkey=os.getenv('wkey')
client = discord.Client()#declaring what the client is.

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ';', intents=intents)#Makes the bot prefix.
```

So honestly i am stuck for how to fix this!

Comment: You need to also enable `intents.reactions`

Comment: Oh, ill try that! I didnt realise that there was a reactions intent

Comment: Also I see that you're defining client two times, there's no need put the first `client = discord.Client()` you're overwriting it two lines later

Comment: I know, Sorry I was using it to make a tutorial, its my new script that I sort of squash everything onto